# Grub won't stop loading

Tags: grub2, gnu

I have just installed Windows 10 and dual booted Ubuntu. I made Ubuntu boot first through the bios I just deleted the partitions for Ubuntu I changed the bios settings so Windows 10 will boot first but grub keeps loading and it is in rescue mode so I can't boot. I am a devoper and have data on windows that if I have to reinstall windows will be lost is there a way I can boot windows 10 through grub then worry about grub once I am back on windows 10? Ps please respond as fast as possible I use this computer for developing and have irreplaceable data on my PC.

Comment: Because you deleted Ubuntu partitions grub does not find the /boot/grub directory from where it should start and get its settings. I believe this link https://superuser.com/questions/681379/how-to-boot-windows-after-uninstalling-ubuntu has an answer for you.

Comment: for saving your files: boot from a live CD, mount the windows partition and copy the data to an external hard drive. You better do this before doing any further steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of issue can usually be resolved in the sort of the same manner whether you're on Win 7/8/10. I don't know exactly how this works for Windows 10 but I would be surprised if it's significantly different.

Windows 7 and 8 has a tool called `bootrec` on the install media that you can use to fix these kinds of boot issues.

- Insert and boot from the Windows install media (USB/DVD)
- Press any key at the "Press any key to boot" message
- Click "Repair your computer" (or similar). <kbd>R</kbd> may also work.
- Select "Troubleshoot", then select Command Prompt. Basically, your first goal here is to get to a command prompt.

So, when you have a command prompt window open and ready, run `bootrec` with whatever commands may be necessary (or all of them) -- these are:

- `bootrec /FixMbr` --  will write a Windows Vista and Windows 7 compatible MBR to the system partition.
- `bootrec /FixBoot` -- will write a new boot sector to the system partition. If your system is Windows 7, FixBoot will write a Windows 7-compatible boot sector and so on.
- `bootrec /ScanOs` will scan the hard drives for any installations. ScanOs will also print installations that are not currently in the BCD.
- `bootrec /RebuildBcd` will scan for installations on your hard drive and allows you to select which to add to the BCD.

When it has finished, remove the USB/DVD and restart your PC.

Source: https://neosmart.net/wiki/bootrec

(The above website also has a lot of potential solutions for errors that occur).